# How can I get Claims from a JWT?

Tags: java, jwt, jose4j

I need to extract claims from a JWT.

It seems that this should be a no-brainer.

It was signed, from the header I get:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

JWT:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJtYXJrLnN0YW5nQGRoaWdyb3VwaW5jLmNvbSIsInNjb3BlIjpbIm9wZW5pZCJdLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJKT0JTRUVLRVIiXSwiam9ic2Vla2VySWQiOiJ3TDFkTWdQckZWOUl5dEZZIiwiZXhwIjoxNDg4Mzk1ODE5LCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJKT0JTRUVLRVIiXSwianRpIjoiNWRiYjNkYzQtNGI3NC00MDYyLTgzMmQtYjE1MTgwYWZhZjllIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiZWZjIn0.NxiF4x39na3KdDUFz2zxqy1zSfJkj4FdKHflpgJUxzMgBq8bbJIFVkmwAUYA6_YXm6kGFcyTMgdiRIJpqc5buDPdV1vkzh4QKFTxMz9MF4i3vtIQ21Vm5W12KikWdWGGUXMD4udJwu7rmuIBtNIa-ciZOPADNrrXfuw7iML1xxAA-C0f4OTbiKqiXr3QEUZwcqZB17qfh_dVRRxgO-_uHUg84JDcpXEDQPzPWX68u1EHH4J6IcpMKn1VY9k3RcZU6pq-ndzQgBlKdVm2owA6i-UM9p1zSz7ZX_2wx0czEEcNF1rMdeIv5yxP9YEpWb14-GUG4qgpn_rAIQBJ7eu7xw

It decodes on the jwt.io site just fine, but since I don't have the "secret" key, it comes up as "invalid signature".  Which is fine, I am not trying to validate it.

All I want is the claims but when I use a Java library to decode it I get nothing but errors.

If I decode it manually (i.e. split/base64 decode) it is fine.

So, what am I doing wrong with the Java libraries?

Comment: How can we answer your question without seeing your code?

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: My code was something I found on SO.  What I am looking for is how to get one of the Libraries to extract the claims without me writing code to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the question is tagged with [jose4j](/questions/tagged/jose4j), I understand you are using [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) for parsing JWT tokens.

In this situation, you can invoke [`setSkipSignatureVerification()`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.4/org/jose4j/jwt/consumer/JwtConsumerBuilder.html#setSkipSignatureVerification()) from the [`JwtConsumerBuilder`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j/0.5.4/org/jose4j/jwt/consumer/JwtConsumerBuilder.html). It allows you to parse the claims without validating the signature:

```java
JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                                  .setSkipSignatureVerification()
                                  .build();
                                                  
JwtClaims jwtClaims = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(jwt);
```

Comment: `alg` is `RS256`, so I guess there will be some public key out there to verify the signature

Comment: @pedrofb Good spot! But for some reason the OP is only concerned about parsing the claims without any signature verification.

Comment: I believe, maybe incorrectly, that adding a dependency on an external piece of data (i.e. the public key) could make my code "brittle".  Any changes in the Key require me to change my code or at least react to the change.  And when that happens my code is broken.

Comment: @ChaosRules What do you mean with you previous comment? Does my solution works for you or not?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to test it.  I think it will work and is what I am looking for.  My previous comment was in regards to using the public key to validate the signature.  Which I don't want to do.

Comment: @ChaosRules As soon as you have a chance to test it, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, it has taken me this long to get back to you, but that worked.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: OK, so now I have a public key and want to verify the signature.  Is there a straightforward mechanism for this?

Comment: The JwtConsumerBuilder wants a RsaJsonWebKey.  I have the public key, but it won't accept a string.

Comment: Maybe a different library?

Comment: OK, figured it out, seems I was mis-informed.  Wrong public key.

Comment: Hello can't we extract jwt from that `extractClaim`

Answer (score 2):

Let me provide a general answer for everyone's use.

I am using this [maven/gradle library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/9.4.2). Use the following for Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>[ version ]</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use the following code to decode and get claims.

```
String jwtToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG...";

JWSObject jwsObject;
JWTClaimsSet claims;

try {
       jwsObject = JWSObject.parse(this.jwt);
       claims =  JWTClaimsSet.parse(jwsObject.getPayload().toJSONObject());
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
       // Invalid JWS object encoding
}

// now access any claims you want using the relevant key. It will be returned as an object
Object expiry = claims.getClaim("exp");
```